# ООП. JavaScript. Не могу принять результат выполнения метода =\

Tags: ооп, javascript

Ребят. Картина такая:

```
function Engine(options)
{
    this.messagesPerPage = options.messagesPerPage;
    this.messages = [];

    this.start = function()
    {

        var that = this;

        var msgs = that.getMessages();

        alert(msgs[0].text);
    }

    this.getMessages = function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: true,
            url:'index.php?controller=cBlog&action=getMsgs',
            data: ({
                limit:this.messagesPerPage
            }),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data.status == 'ok') 
                {
                    return data.messages;
                }
            },
            error: function()
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

при загрузке страницы отрабатывает метод start() и беда в том, что getMessages() внутри него ничего не возвращает, хотя и отрабатывает как положено. Возвращает корректный json. Запарился уже= Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с тем, что я делаю не так

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем коде `getMessages()` начинает `ajax` запрос и нечего не возвращает. Результат `json` приходит в функцию `success`, которая по идее и должна проделать какую-то работу.

Comment: спасибо. как же я так протупил о_О